# need a date picker with this format dd-MON-yy

Tags: php, oracle, date

i have to fetch rows from oracle database which have specific dates. i use a date picker and want when select a date, all rows of that date comes to fron page of php. in oracle date formate is like 15-MAR-14 means dd-MON-yy. but my date picker can show date like 15-03-14 or 15-3-14 which doesn't match oracle database date format, and as a result it shows an error "not a valid month" . any one please tell me about a date picker for a php form that when i click a date show like dd-MON-yy i.e, 12-MAR-14.
please if you know any link or source for uch date picker kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work like this if you need more detail check the link belong.

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-MON-yy" );
  });
  </script>
```

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats